# IdentityServer 4: Invalid grant type for client: authorization_code

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I'm trying to authorize my angular client with identity server. following are the settings for my angular client.

```
  authority: 'http://localhost:5000',
  client_id: 'clientid',
  redirect_uri: 'https://localhost:44384/auth-callback',
  post_logout_redirect_uri: 'https://localhost:44384/',
  response_type: "code",
  scope: "openid profile",
  filterProtocolClaims: true,
  loadUserInfo: true,
  automaticSilentRenew: true,
  silent_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:44384/silent-refresh.html'
```

Similar client is registered at IdentityServer side.

```
 new Client
 {
     ClientId = "clientid",     
     AllowedScopes = { "openid", "profile" },
     AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
     RequirePkce = true,
     RequireClientSecret = false,
     AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
     AllowOfflineAccess = false,
     AccessTokenLifetime = 3600,
     RedirectUris={"https://localhost:44384/auth-callback" },
     PostLogoutRedirectUris=  {"https://localhost:44384/" },
     RequireConsent= false
  }
```

and it was working fine. but when i moved the same client settings to database, its giving me  **Invalid grant type for client**.

Following are VS logs

```
[15:15:56 Debug] IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.ClientStore
clientid found in database: True

[15:15:56 Debug] IdentityServer4.Stores.ValidatingClientStore
client configuration validation for client clientid succeeded.

[15:15:56 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator
Checking for PKCE parameters

[15:15:56 Error] IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator: Invalid grant type for client: authorization_code
```

Database data for client is as following.

[image]

and for grantType.

[image]

Comment: Can you share what is in your database?

Comment: @mackie question is updated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have figured it out. The `GrantType` I have mentioned in Database is wrong.

I was writing following code when getting clients from memory. i.e. from `appsettings.json` file

```
 new Client
 {
     -------
     -------
     AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
     --------
     --------
}
```

And later when I have moved this information to database, I mistakenly used the same `grantType` i.e. `Code`, which is wrong. It should be defined like `authorization_code`.

So by changing `GrantType` in database from `Code` to `authorization_code`. fixed my issue.